# Add to javascript associative array

Tags: javascript

I want the following structure:

```
    var data={"users":[
    {
        "firstName":"Ray",
        "lastName":"Villalobos",
        "joined":2012
    },
    {
        "firstName":"John",
        "lastName":"Jones",
        "joined":2010
    }
    ]}
```

I want to be able to programatically add entries to it.
Here is what I tried:

```
  var data = [];
   data.push({
     "firstName":"Johsssn",
     "lastName":"Jossnes",
     "joined":2010
   });
```

Comment: And what have you got trying? Error?

Comment: yep,jcsanyi's solution solved it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your array is actually `data.users`, not `data`.
So use this instead:

```
var data = {users: []};
data.users.push({
  "firstName":"Johsssn",
  "lastName":"Jossnes",
  "joined":2010
});
```

Comment: This is how I'd do it.  Also, you can use bracket notation (`data["users"]`) instead of dot notation (`data.users`).

Answer (score 0):

```
    var data = {users: []};
    data.users.push({
         "firstName":"Johsssn",
         "lastName":"Jossnes",
         "joined":2010
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `data` object contains one property, `users`, which is an array of users, so you need to push into it:

```
data.users.push({
    "firstName":"Johsssn",
    "lastName":"Jossnes",
     "joined":2010
});
```